# jQuery window width conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I'm having a bit of trouble with adjusting the code according to window width. If the window width is less than 450, I want it to scroll to a certain part, else another. Where am I going wrong?

```
$('.artist-kina').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        if ($(window).width() < 450 {
            scrollTop: $('#artists').offset().top - 60
        }
        else {
            scrollTop: $('#artists').offset().top - 115
        }
    }, 500);
    $('.artists-home').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.kina-gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: You have forgotten a parentheses in your if structure: `if ($(window).width())`

Comment: @Pieter I put that in and now I'm getting an error on that line for an unexpected `(`. Here's the error: `Error on line 148 col 6 Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:»`

Comment: ^ put the parantesis after 450 so `if ($(window).width() < 450) {`

Comment: @Arijoon I did that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: My mistake, typed to fast!

Comment: Try taking your `if` statement outside `animate`, then assign the value to a variable accordingly and set `scrollTop` to that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthesis was a problem, but in a larger sense the syntax is just completely wrong:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#artists").offset().top - (
      $(window).width() < 450 ? 60 : 115
    )
}, 500);
```

You can't just drop an `if` statement into the middle of an object literal. You can, however, use the `? :` operator to make a choice between values as part of an expression.

Now be aware that fooling around with the scroll position of the `<body>` may or may not work in all browsers. Safari *used to* have a problem with that; it may work in more modern versions of the browser.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing but the way you wrote it is very neat. +1

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps and I'll remember this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with the way that you nested the code, but the largest issue was the Animate call.

This should work:

```
$('.artist-kina').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(window).width() < 450) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $('#artists').offset().top-60
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $('#artists').offset().top-115
        }, 500);
    }
    $('.artists-home').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.kina-gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yy1v940u/5/